# How to make text wrap with diff -y?

Tags: linux, command, diff, line

When I use `diff -y` to compare two text files with long lines of text, the result cuts off each column and I cannot read an entire line. I would like instead the text to wrap (or fold as it is also called) so that I can read the whole line.

For example, say I have two simple text files one line each:

```
cat tmp.txt tmp2.txt
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. This line is very long and will not show when I use a diff. 
The quick brown fox did not jump over the lazy dog. This line is very long and will not show when I use a diff.
```

`diff`ing them I get,

```
diff -y tmp.txt tmp2.txt
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. This line is ve | The quick brown fox did not jump over the lazy dog. This line
```

which cuts off the lines in the middle.

I know about the `-W` option to make it wider, but the lines are longer than my screen width so this does not help. Using a simple `diff` does make the text wrap, but there is no text wrapping with `diff -y`.

So how can I use `diff -y` with text wrapping?

I'm using the terminal on a Mac, if that helps.

This seems like a simple thing to want, but after searching everywhere I cannot find a solution!

Comment: "I'm using the terminal on a Mac" and yet this is tagged "Linux"

Comment: if it is ok to lose original line numbers, if you just want to see the visual diff ?

Answer (score 5):

If it is ok to lose line number information , and you are just interested in visual diffs, you could `fold` the files first before diffing them.

```
diff -y <(fold -s -w72 file1) <(fold -s -w72 file2) -W 200
```

In this command we have used process substitution to first fold each file to line of 72 characters, but with `-s` option we ensure that the lines are broken only on the space character.

Once the lines are wrapped by fold, diff command would work on the wrapped output.

EDIT: specifying -W to diff with a larger value than that given in the fold will ensure that the diff and fold have sufficient space to work with each other. In this case -W 200 is given to diff

Comment: Please also consider expanding width of `diff` command with `-W` option. It seemed handy when used along with your answer ,example: `diff -y <(fold -s -w72 file1) <(fold -s -w72 file2) -W 200`. Not all lines were folded properly with just `diff -y <(fold -s -w72 file1) <(fold -s -w72 file2)`. Also not all line were wrapped properly with just `diff -y <(fold -s -w72 file1) <(fold -s -w72 file2) -W 200`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Do mark this the accepted answer in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `icdiff` for this task.

The screenshot after running  `icdiff tmp.txt tmp1.txt`:

[image: icdiff outputs]

Comment: vimdiff is my prefrence

Comment: Icdiff works to some degree, but if lines on the right are longer than those on the left, just a newline is inserted so that the end of the right-hand line appears on the left. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`Kdiff3` has a setting `Diffview > Word Wrap Diff Windows` which breaks lines at the closest word boundary in the frame. It is the only tool I have found that does this.

[image: kdiff3 showing diff of two texts with word wrap]